# propagate errors up the call stack - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nserror

In a typical layered architecture, how can I effectively communicate errors originating in data access layer to a `UIViewContoller`?

I have following design:

> `UIViewController`s --> datacontroller --> specificserviceproxy --> serviceproxybase

serviceproxybase initiates calls to a web service. I check for network availability before invoking operations on the web service, and want to alert users in case of network breakdown.

What is the best practice solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the pattern used my much of Cocoa-touch. Many methods return `nil` or `NO` when there is an error and such methods have an `NSError` out parameter with details about the error.

You can propagate the result and error up the layers as needed. Or a layer may wrap the error with a more layer specific error and pass up the new error.

Example methods that follow this pattern are:

```
NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:
NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:
```

Comment: Good plan. An addendum: consider carefully which errors are worth presenting to the user, and how you present them. In a mobile environment you should expect spotty connectivity, and your user shouldn't be having to dismiss an alert every 30 seconds just because your automatic fetch-tweets-in-the-background connection is failing. Report errors unobtrusively if at all, or only in response to direct user action.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply guys. i am confused now on my implementation choice. both the options seems logical to me. what are the factors influencing my decision?

Comment: My answer is useful when you need the error handled only by the immediate caller of the method (even if the error is just propagated up to the previous caller. The answer with notifications is a better choice if you need to have several objects be notified about a given error, not just the caller of the method that gave the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think NSError out parameter is ideal in my case where I check for network connectivity before making a service call in response user action for fetching or saving data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to post and receive `NSNotification`s for various error states.

In `serviceproxybase` you would post the notification for any interested observers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NoConnectionNotification" object:nil userInfo:someErrorInfoObject];
```

Typically you would package up an object in `someErrorInfoObject` that gives some additional details to the observer, such as an `NSError` object, the service request that failed, or a service's error code.  In a view controller you would listen for that notification in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleNoConnectionError:)
                                             name:@"NoConnectionNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now whenever a notification with the name `NoConnectionNotification` is posted, the view controller will receive a message to `handleNoConnectionError:` with the corresponding `NSNotification`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply guys. i am confused now on my implementation choice. both the options seems logical to me. what are the factors influencing my decision?

Comment: Thanks jszumski. I have a scenario where I need to broadcast a message to multiple objects and this would really come in handy. Thanks for sharing your wisdom.